# How to get better lemmas from Spacy

Tags: python, nlp, wordnet, spacy, lemmatization

While "PM" can mean "pm(time)" it can also mean "Prime Minister".

I want to capture the latter. I want lemma of "PM" to return "Prime Minister". How can I do this using `spacy`?

Example returning unexpected lemma:

```
>>> import spacy
>>> #nlp = spacy.load('en')
>>> nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
>>> doc = nlp(u'PM means prime minister')
>>> for word in doc:
...     print(word.text, word.lemma_)
... 
PM pm
means mean
prime prime
minister minister
```

As per doc https://spacy.io/api/annotation, spacy uses WordNet for lemmas;

> A lemma is the uninflected form of a word. The English lemmatization data is taken from WordNet..

When I tried inputting "pm" in [Wordnet](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=pm&sub=Search%20WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=0000), it shows "Prime Minister" as one of the lemmas.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you please review the existing answers and either approve them if they answer your question or further clarify what you need? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would help answer your question by clarifying some common NLP tasks.

**Lemmatization** is the process of finding the canonical word given different inflections of the word. For example, run, runs, ran and running are forms of the same lexeme: run. If you were to lemmatize *run*, *runs*, and *ran* the output would be *run*. In your example sentence, note how it lemmatizes *means* to *mean*.

Given that, it doesn't sound like the task you want to perform is lemmatization. It may help to solidify this idea with a silly counterexample: what are the different inflections of a hypothetical lemma "pm": pming, pmed, pms? None of those are actual words.

It sounds like your task may be closer to **Named Entity Recognition** (NER), which you could also do in spaCy. To iterate through the detected entities in a parsed document, you can use the `.ents` attribute, as follows:

```
>>> for ent in doc.ents:
...     print(ent, ent.label_)
```

With the sentence you've given, spacy (v. 2.0.5) doesn't detect any entities. If you replace "PM" with "P.M." it will detect that as an entity, but as a GPE.

The best thing to do depends on your task, but if you want your desired classification of the "PM" entity, I'd look at [setting entity annotations](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#setting-entities). If you want to pull out every mention of "PM" from a big corpus of documents, [use the matcher in a pipeline](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#component-example2).

Answer (score 0):

When I run lemmas of prime minister on nltk.wordnet (which uses it as well) I get:

`>>>[str(lemma.name()) for lemma in wn.synset('prime_minister.n.01').lemmas()]  ['Prime_Minister', 'PM', 'premier']`

It keeps acronyms the same so maybe you want to check word.lemma() which would give you a different ID according to the context?